# load balancing postgres instances via aws network balancer possible?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have an application that has multiple postgres databases (that are guaranteed to be in sync) installed on AWS EC2 instances in different availability zones. I would like to abstract them behind a single DNS so that, if one of the EC2 instances crashes, the clients can still access the db. I am wondering if I can use an AWS network load balancer to load balance my databases? Why or why not? If not, is there any other standard, easy-to-implement solution that I can use? (I am aware of http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page for example. However, am leery of using something that I have to setup myself, especially since I would have to replicate pgpool instances as well...)

Comment: Are your databases read-only or read/write? The former should be easy, the latter could raise quite a few issues. Your should be able to use ELB in Classic or Network modes (not Application), as they support raw TCP. Be wary of authentication and other security issues, you don’t want to open up access to your database to everybody.

Comment: @jcaron the dbs are read/write (with regard to permissions) but the application server (multi instance application) accessing it is only doing reads. What security issues are you referring to (assuming that I only allow the application server's security group into the db)?

Comment: What about configuring your web server health checks to verify that they can access the database?  If a server has no DB access, it fails its health check, and the load balancer for the web server takes it out if service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having just tried it myself, it does seem you can set up a network load balancer to load balance your databases.  My production setup uses [patroni](https://github.com/zalando/patroni) to manage failover, and patroni provides an HTTP API for health checks.  The master returns a 200 response, while the replicas return a 503.  This works fine for my use case, where the replicas are there just for failover, not for replicated reads.  I'm assuming you could come up with some code that returns a successful response for health checks based on your needs.

I configured the load balancer to listen to port 5432 and the health checks to connect on port 8008.  I modified the security group for the postgres instances to allow connections from my VPC's IP range, since the NLB doesn't have security groups. Connecting via psql to the NLB's DNS name worked as expected.

Though it works, I think I'll stick with my current setup, which has a PgBouncer running on each application instance (so no need to worry managing a pool of bouncer instances) with consul-template updating pgbouncer.ini and reloading PgBouncer when the leader key changes in consul.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Very useful indeed. A couple of follow up questions. 1) When using the NLB does the client establish a connection on each transaction? 2) Does that depend on the client (I am using http://docs.sequelizejs.com/)? 3) How do you setup pgbouncer on the application instance? 4) Do you run it as a docker container or do you have application start it up? 5) I am using a node.js, do you know of any easy way for me to run pgBouncer? 6) Do you have a link to a .INI file for multiple dbs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. I don't know, I didn't test it long enough to answer that
2. Can't say, I only tried psql
3-4. I run pgbouncer via systemd, and the application's service file depends on pgbouncer's.
5. Running it via systemd/upstart/init is the way I'd do it. :)
6. I don't, but you just need to define multiple host lines in the ini file.